# How to Serialize/deserialize a generic hand rolled collection of interfaces

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I know you can't serialise an interface, but for the purposes of this discussion there is a 1 to 1 mapping between Interface and Domain Data class so I'm assuming/hoping there is a way to tell the serializer to use the domain class when it sees a given interface.

I have a fairly simple hierarchy object structure

- Profile < Standard class

  - Elements < Hand rolled collection of an interface Class: Nodes(Of IProfile)

    - Element < Standard class
  - Studies < Hand rolled collection Class: Nodes(Of IStudy)

    - Study < Standard class

The declaration of the Elements collection looks like:

```
Public Class Elements
   Inherits Domain.Nodes(Of Domain.IElement)
   Implements Domain.IElements

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal pItems As IEnumerable(Of Domain.IElement))
        MyBase.New(pItems)
    End Sub

End Class
```

For other reasons I'm not inheriting from List(Of T) or keyed collection or anything, Nodes is the hand rolled collection, however I am implementing IEnumerable(Of T) in the Nodes(Of T) base class.

So I am trying to Serialize/Deserialize to XML in the least pain and effort possible. I have been guided to use `<DataContract()>`, `<CollectionDataContract()>` and `<DataMember()>` but am willing to consider other options.

My Deserialize function currently looks like:

```
Private Shared Function Deserialize(ByVal pFilePath As String) As Domain.IProfile
    Dim lNewItem As Domain.IProfile
    Dim lProfileSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Domain.Profile))
    lNewItem = CType(lProfileSerializer.Deserialize(Store.OpenFile(pFilePath, IO.FileMode.Open)), Domain.Profile)
    Return lNewItem
End Function
```

SO how you would you recommend I approach this? Is there an easy attribute I can use to say to the CollectionDataContract "Create the child class as 'Element'" ...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a lot regarding XML serialization as yet but I reckon you will also need to add the Serializable attribute to your Class or whatever. Please note that there are certain things the attribute can not be applied to though.

See:>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class ExampleClass

End Class
```

Comment: thanks I had read through that, the reason I was asking the question is that it was unclear how to handle collections using either <Serializable()> or <DataContract()> when the collection holds an interface ... basically I was hoping to hear <Serializable("ChildClass = MyClass")> or similar